# Linux shell: How can I remove leading/trailing characters before/after specific characters inside a string?

Tags: bash, shell, replace

**Case** scenario:

```
$ var="This is my ___ va__riable ___for___ num_ber ___45___"
$ echo $var
This is my ___ va__riable ___for___ the num_ber ___45___
```

I would like `var` to be **transformed** so that `___N___`  (3 leading `_`, any number, and 3 trailing `_`) will become just `N`, this is: just leave the number.

So the resulting `var` should be:

```
This is my ___ va__riable ___for___ the num_ber 45
```

Note that only 3 consecutive `_` **surrounding a number** are removed. The rest are left.

How could I do this?

My (weak) approach:

```
echo $var | sed 's/___[0-9]___/[0-9]/'
```

(I was thinking about some way for `sed` to replace the number with the same number, but I don't know if this can be done with `sed`).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/___\([0-9][0-9]*\)___/\1/g'
```

You can also use extended regexes:

```
$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/___([0-9]+)___/\1/g'
```

Comment: Would this answer be valid for any digits number?

Comment: There is a theoretical upper bound, but for all practical purposes the answer is "yes".